# Set boundaries for integer input

Tags: java, input, limit

I have this small snippet of coding that requires an input from the user when it is ran to determine a certain value. I don't want the user to be able to enter anything less than 0 and anything greater than 1 million, so, 0 =< YEARS_AHEAD =< 1000000.

I've looked through so many tutorials and searched for help on this and found nothing. This is my code.

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int YEARS_AHEAD;
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of years ahead: ");
    while (true)
        try {
            YEARS_AHEAD = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
            break;
        }catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.print("This value must be an integer, please enter the number of years ahead again: ");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple if:

```
if (YEARS_AHEAD < 0 || YEARS_AHEAD > 1000000) {
  // say something to the user, retry entering the number
}
```

Another option is to use the while cycle for this:

```
int YEARS_AHEAD = -1; // invalid value
while (YEARS_AHEAD < 0 || YEARS_AHEAD > 1000000) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of years ahead: ");
        YEARS_AHEAD = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    }catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.print("This value must be an integer, please enter the number of years ahead again: ");
    }  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as if I enter a letter as my answer, it's returning the second system.out.print and the first system.out.print

I'm new to Java so if you could dumb it down for me, that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have read the input

```
YEARS_AHEAD = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
```

check using `if-else` whether the input is permitted or not.

```
if(YEARS_AHEAD < 0 || YEARS_AHEAD >1000000){
   System.out.println("Invalid Input");
  }else{
     // do your processing here.
 }
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working at all. Maybe a more dumbed down version?